# how to remove a nested element from a clone element?

Tags: jquery

how to remove a nested element from a clone element? Code below is my attempt remove the clone input element but is not working. I'm getting an empty output.

```
 <li id="listA"><p><input class='input1' /><strong id="s1"></strong><strong id="s2"></strong></p></li>

   var $cloneList = $("#listA").clone();
   $cloneList.each(function()
   {
       alert($(this).children().children().remove().html());
   })
```

The goal is to have the following output...

```
  <li id="listA"><p><strong id="s1"></strong><strong id="s2"></strong></p></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $cloneList = $("#listA").clone(); 
$cloneList.find("input.input1").remove();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? An `alert()` showing the html like in your question? (I had assumed that was some sort of debugging device and not part of your real requirement.) Or do you want to append the clone to the page somewhere?